# How to subtract unkown strings from list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that you say to it, from now on call me Jason, then will convert it into a list and subtract everything but Jason from the list. I managed to make this but, i want it to subtract words that aren't in there but would be able to if they were there.

Comment: it is not clear what you mean, and you haven't posted any code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask and edit your question. Your code could offer us insight.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code, so here is how I would do it.

```
names = set(['John','Jason','Jim'])

callme = 'Jason'

names.intersection(set([callme]))
```

Alternatively, with iterators

```
names = ['John','Jason','Jim']

callme = ['Jason']

[N for N in names if N in callme]
```